# Creating perl hash from array values

Tags: perl

i have array by using array need to create perl hash..Example : @array =(1,2,3,4,5,6)
the hash should be 1->2->3->4->6 .Please help any body

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking! Is number 5 missing from your hash intentionally?

Comment: What did you attempt and what were your results?

Comment: "the hash should be 1->2->3->4->6". What does that even mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can,

```
my @array =(1,2,3,4,5,6);
my %hash = @array;
```

which will produce hash like `1=>2, 3=>4, 5=>6`, and

```
my %hash = map { ($array[$_]) x (1+ ($_ && $_< $#array)) } 0 .. $#array;
```

will produce hash like `1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>4, 4=>5, 5=>6`

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to create `%hash=(1=>2,3=>4,5=>6)` mpapec's answer is the right one.
- If you want to create `%hash=(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3,4=>4,5=>5,6=>6)` you can do the following:

  ```
  my @array=(1,2,3,4,5,6);
  my %hash;
  for (@array) {
      $hash{$_}=$_
  }
  ```
- If you want don't care about values, only keys, you can do the following:

  ```
  my @array=(1,2,3,4,5,6);
  my %hash;
  @hash{@array}=1;  #will produce %hash=(1=>1,2=>undef,3=>undef,4=>undef,5=>undef,6=>undef)
  ```